# how to control the animationImages?

Tags: uiimageview, uibutton

i use the following code

```
imgview.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],nil ];

    imgview.animationDuration=1.0;
    imgview.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [imgview startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imgview];
```

here imgview is UIImageView, but now i want to use a IBAction of UIButton for control this. The default image is 1.png, when i click the button, the imgview will show the next image.
such as when the current image is 1.png, it will show 2.png when i clicked the button, it will show 3.png when i clicked the button again, and go on. if the current image is 5.png, it will show 1.png when i clicked the button, so how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the the current image in a property in your viewController such as currentImage, this can be an int with the position on the array, then you can simply get the currentImage + 1 from the array. Something like this:

```
// On view initialization
currentImage = 0;

NSArray myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],nil ];
```

imgview.animationImages = myArray;

```
//callback from UIButton when pressed.
if (currentImage + 1 >= [myArray count]) {
    currentImage = 0;
}

UIImage myDisplayedImage = [myArray objectAtIndex:currentImage];
currentImage++;
```

Comment: some errors, xcode tells me error"myArray",can you give me the full code?thanks